# Why my script is "Terminated" after few hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a script (written in Node.js) that mostly sleeps, wakes up every few minutes, reads something form /proc, writes something to log file and continues sleeping. On my own machines it works without problem for days but on AWS EC2 Linux the script gets "Terminated" (this is the exact message, it just get returned to bash prompt) every few hours without any other message. Largest timespan it survived before termination was 24 hours.

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXX ~]$ node myscript.js
.......................Terminated
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXX ~]$
```

(My script prints a dot every hour).

Comment: Please edit the question to give more details about what you mean by "AWS" (EC2? Lambda? Something else? What instance type? What image?) and what you mean by "Terminated" (What is the exact message and where does it appear? Is it your script that terminates, or the whole instance?)

Comment: `ec2-user` implies it's running on an EC2 instance.  from the look of it ( `Termianted`, just like that) I'd say it's receiving the TERM signal - would you agree? Could be from any number of things, but it's happening from within the instance.  AWS can't inject signals into your EC2 instance's operating system unless you're running some AWS agent inside for code deploy or command or something.  It might be memory or resource constraints.  Logs might provide more information